# What should I do with the unused diode in the SOT-323-3 (SC-70-3) package?

Tags: diodes, packages, performance, dual

[image]

I'm planning to use one of [this diode](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/M1MA141KT1-D.PDF) in my circuit. But the package contains two of them. I chose it mainly because of its 3ns reverse recovery time. How do I use them in my circuit?

I have three options in my mind if you won't suggest a forth one.

1. Use one, leave the other open.
2. Connect them parallel.
3. Use one, connect the unused device pin to a rail with a very large resistor.

How do I get the best switching characteristics?

Comment: I was going to say option 2 until I read that you chose the part for its RR.

Comment: 4. Use one and short the unused anode to the cathode.

Comment: Yep, I was just about to mention that.

Comment: @brhans Why don't you post it as an answer along with a little explanation?

Comment: Make sure that you use the diode on the left, so that you can substitute the single-diode part.  (which seems to be more widely available than common-cathode anyway.)

Comment: Get an x-acto knife, cut one diode out, and post it to me. I'll make use of it.

Comment: wiring diodes in parallel is generally not a great idea (thermal runaway and so on), but maybe they are very well matched since their probably on the same die...

Comment: @vicatcu Thermal runaway is not an issue here since only one of them are enough capable of carrying the current.